# how to make std::function instance

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++0x, we use use `std::function` like the following:

```
int normal_function() {
    return 42;
}
std::function<int()> f = normal_function;
```

So to get an `std::function` instance, we have to define its type firstly. But it's boring and sometimes hard.

So, can we just use make to get a `std::function` instance just like `std::tuple`?

In fact, I just googled, C++0x doesn't provide such make facility.

Why C++0x no provide make facility? 
Can we implement it?

Comment: @thiton: How would auto help here?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes, on the second thought the line `auto f = normal_function;` (which I had in mind) is pointless. Sorry.

Comment: @thiton why is that idea pointless?

Comment: @balki: Because it declares a function pointer, not a std::function.

Comment: the real question is... why would you want a `std::function` object for `normal_function`? Just pass `normal_function` to the function/method which requires a function object... ?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes we can implement it

```
template<typename T>
std::function<T> make_function(T *t) {
  return { t };
}
```

This requires that you pass a function to `make_function`. To prevent overload to pick this up for something other than a plain function, you can SFINAE it

```
template<typename T>
std::function<
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_function<T>::value, T>::type
> make_function(T *t) {
  return { t };
}
```

You cannot pass it class type function objects though and no member pointers. For arbitrary function objects there is no way to obtain a call signature (what would you do if the respective `operator()` is a template?). This probably is the reason that C++11 provides no such facility.

Comment: It'd probably be possible to extend to bind expressions and other such things where the type information follows a well known and standard structure. I've been wanting a wrapper that allowed me to pass in a `weak_ptr` to `mem_fn` and just have the call silently no-op if the `weak_ptr` was dead.

Comment: You can use `std::mem_fn` to handle member function pointers.