# Template substitution failure with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to pass a callback function as function parameter. But getting template substitution failure errors in following code. Not sure why template substitution is failing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template<typename A,typename B>
void myfun(std::map<A,B> & mm, std::function<std::tuple<A,B>(void)> fn)
{
    A key;
    B val;
    std::tie(key,val) = fn();
    mm[key] = val;
}

std::tuple<std::string,int> fun()
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::string("hi"),1);
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,int> gg;
#if 0
        //fixed version
        std::function<std::tuple<std::string,int>(void)> yy = fun;//fixed
        myfun(gg,yy);//fixed
#else
        // error causing code
        myfun(gg,fun);
#endif
}
```

And error is as following

```
main.cpp:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:25:17: note:   mismatched types 'std::function<std::tuple<_T1, _T2>()>' and 'std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> (*)()'

     myfun(gg,fun);
```

Comment: `"hi"` might be deduced to `const char*`, try to use `std::string("hi")`

Comment: `std::function` and ordinary functions are different things, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054774/difference-between-stdfunction-and-a-standard-function-pointer .

Comment: @JohannesWalcher or the much nicer `"hi"s` with C++14

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler can't both cast to a `std::function` and deduce the template arguments. It doesn't understand the mapping between an arbitrary function pointer and a `std::function`.

There are a few ways round this.

You could explicitly create a `std::function` at the call site:

```
 myfun(gg,std::function<std::tuple<std::string,int>(void)>{fun});`
```

You could write a `make_function` function to deduce the types for you. You can find discussions and implementations of this online, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825559/why-is-there-no-stdmake-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670810/how-to-make-stdfunction-instance) and [here](https://gist.github.com/duckie/24d7ea892299335f1916).

```
myfun(gg,make_function(fun));
```

You could just forget about `std::function` and deduce the entire function type. This is the approach I would take:

```
template<typename A,typename B, typename Fun>
void myfun(std::map<A,B> & mm, Fun fn)
{
    A key;
    B val;
    std::tie(key,val) = fn();
    mm[key] = val;
}
```

Comment: When you say the compiler can't both do the cast and the deduction, are you saying that it's against the rules or just that the compiler isn't bright enough to do it?